# Unable to merge Accounts due to Account Team Members

Tags: merge, account-teams

A user tries to merge two duplicate accounts and is getting the insufficient permissions error.
The user has delete permission on accounts, opps and contacts.

Both accounts are owned by the same user (Nathalie). The non-master account has an account team including:

- Anthony with read/write access on accounts, cases and opps
- Nathalie (owner) with read/write access on accounts, cases and opps

The master account has no account team.

The merging works only if Anthony is deleted from the account team. I am trying to find an explanation for that.

So far I found this on SF Help:
'To merge accounts to which a team member has greater record level access, you must have the Modify All Data permission on accounts.'
Anthony has only read/write access on the non-master account, cases and opps. My merging user is not included in the account team but in general he has CRED permissions on accounts and related objects (no deletion on cases but we don't use them anyway).

What am I missing here?

Comment: You've literally quoted the reason: Natalie would need Modify All Data in order to merge the accounts, even though she owns both accounts.

Comment: I'm not sure if that's tha answer. Anthony as a team member doesn't have a greater record level access. His access is exactly the same as Nathalie's (owner and 2nd team member). What's more important, the user merging the accounts has even higher record level access.

Comment: I mean to say, I'm pretty sure they're specifying that if Anthony's Read/Write access on the Team Member record exceeds the Organization-Wide Defaults, then Natalie needs Modify All Data permission to merge the accounts.